# Calculating distances between each possible pair of geometries in a data set

Tags: r

I've a data set of shapefiles for which I would like to calculate the distance between each possible pair of geometries. For simplicity purposes, I'm using linestrings in the example.

```r
library(tidyverse)  
library(sf)
  
df <- structure(list(pair = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), name = c("a", 
"b", "a", "d", "a", "f", "a", "h", "a", "j"), geometry = c("LINESTRING (147.283284394071 29.3287910800427, -0.288163712248206 -3.09525333344936)", 
"LINESTRING (-157.729265335947 -48.1473728455603, 7.03633622266352 -2.49763372354209)", 
"LINESTRING (-92.2604528535157 51.9686110317707, 128.339176392183 -4.87301101908088)", 
"LINESTRING (109.136072024703 -23.0982730910182, 32.643486270681 -56.4928408619016)", 
"LINESTRING (-156.745420424268 44.4007918797433, -146.52594239451 -11.4417109452188)", 
"LINESTRING (121.660849191248 33.3559756167233, -146.58755114302 42.7209938596934)", 
"LINESTRING (157.044121026993 -27.3180517181754, 25.5858838185668 31.0715377237648)", 
"LINESTRING (-61.0889649018645 -22.5691091828048, 170.99352736026 51.8995026592165)", 
"LINESTRING (121.156455930322 -6.1884834151715, 159.309913236648 -31.6152674239129)", 
"LINESTRING (-107.764133261517 -26.5072314999998, 25.1957645639777 -59.3435900844634)"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>     pair name  geometry                                                         
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>                                                            
#>  1     1 a     LINESTRING (147.283284394071 29.3287910800427, -0.28816371224820…
#>  2     1 b     LINESTRING (-157.729265335947 -48.1473728455603, 7.0363362226635…
#>  3     2 a     LINESTRING (-92.2604528535157 51.9686110317707, 128.339176392183…
#>  4     2 d     LINESTRING (109.136072024703 -23.0982730910182, 32.643486270681 …
#>  5     3 a     LINESTRING (-156.745420424268 44.4007918797433, -146.52594239451…
#>  6     3 f     LINESTRING (121.660849191248 33.3559756167233, -146.58755114302 …
#>  7     4 a     LINESTRING (157.044121026993 -27.3180517181754, 25.5858838185668…
#>  8     4 h     LINESTRING (-61.0889649018645 -22.5691091828048, 170.99352736026…
#>  9     5 a     LINESTRING (121.156455930322 -6.1884834151715, 159.309913236648 …
#> 10     5 j     LINESTRING (-107.764133261517 -26.5072314999998, 25.195764563977…
```

I'm using `sf::st_distance()` to calculate the distance between each geometry. Passing a vector of geometries to `st_distance()` doesn't suit me because the values of the resulting matrix are hard to implement in the data set later on. Instead, I'd like to calculate the distances directly in the data set.

Below is how I'm doing it at the moment:

```r
df |> 
  st_as_sf(wkt = "geometry") |> 
  mutate(distance = {
    out <- st_distance(geometry)
    out <- unique(as.numeric(out))
    if (length(out) > 1L) {
      out[out != 0]
    } else {
      out
    }
  }, .by = pair)
```

That works but it's slow. I've close to 50,000 pairs and some shapefiles have complex geometries.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it?

I may try to split the data set in 4 and run the code in parallel for each smaller data sets but I'm open to any suggestion to make the code run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your pairs are consecutive as in your sample data, then you can do it in one call to `st_distance` with the odd and even rows separated.

```
df = st_as_sf(df,wkt="geometry")
n = nrow(df)
dd = st_distance(df[seq(1,n,2),],df[seq(2,n,2),],by_element=TRUE)
dd
### [1]   0.9881316  22.4403295   9.6895375   0.0000000 109.6992236
```

These are the same numbers as you get from your code, except not repeated. Assuming dist(a,b) = dist(b,a) then to reconstruct that repeated value vector:

```
dd2 = rep(dd, rep(2, length(dd)))
dd2
## [1]   0.9881316   0.9881316  22.4403295  22.4403295   9.6895375   9.6895375
## [7]   0.0000000   0.0000000 109.6992236 109.6992236
```

You could then add that to your dataframe as a new column.

Comment: Thanks. That's slightly faster, although that means one has to wrap that in a function to use it in a pipe chain. BTW, `dd2` can be simplified as follows `rep(dd, each = 2)`.

Comment: Wrapping things in functions is always a good idea. Adding more things to a pipe chain seldom is.